# Why is S01 E09 of "Colony" called "Zero Day"?

Tags: title, colony

Why is the episode 9 season 1 of "Colony" called "Zero Day"? Is this some reference to  Columbine High School massacre that inspired filming a movie called "Zero Day"? Or is it related to revolution? "restarting and going all over again" in fighting with aliens?

Comment: "*These were the locations of four of the largest "Zero Day" attacks*". [Transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=525&t=25886)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)

Answer (score 4):

Notably, the opening scene scrawl for this episode reads "366 days". Families are releasing [sky lanterns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_lantern) with the faces of other people who are not there attached to them; those others are likely missing or dead.  The families are mourning together.

We would assume "Zero Day" refers to the annual anniversary of the public exposure to the alien invasion; specifically, the day the walls came down, during which many were likely killed or separated.

The episode (or part of it) takes place on this "Zero Day" anniversary.